# How to get product's price based on latest date in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have following Table:

[image]

The first column of the above table is "Product Name", the second column is for the "Date" in which the prices were updated and the third column represents the price of the respective dates.

What I would like to accomplish, getting the price of the product (let's say, "Engerix" in this case) from C1:C5, based on the latest date in B1:B5. So, actually I want the value is to be "700" in this case.

I have used excel INDEX, MATCH and MAX formula to accomplish the expected result but as I am a novice, I failed. Anyone here to help me in this regard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend formatting column B like this

```
d-mmm-yy h:mm:ss
```

This will ensure a more accurate result otherwise this will sum anything on the day.

**F2**

```
=SUMIFS($C$2:$C$7,$A$2:$A$7,E2,$B$2:$B$7,MAX(IF($A$2:$A$9=E2,$B$2:$B$9)))
```

**F3**

```
=SUMIFS($C$2:$C$7,$A$2:$A$7,E3,$B$2:$B$7,MAX(IF($A$2:$A$9=E3,$B$2:$B$9)))
```

[image]

> You have an accidental "@" in your F3 code, remove this and should
>   work.

[image]

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your message. Don't know why the formula in F3 does not work although the same formula works at F2. Reference to E2 has been changed to E3 as usual.

Comment: Please upload a screenshot of your sheet or a copy @AbdullahMamun-Ur-Rashid

Comment: @AbdullahMamun-Ur-Rashid also make sure theres no spaces behind E3 or any of the Engerix rows in column A

Comment: I just surprised, there is no @ code in my excel sheet.

Comment: Copy and paste my F3 on my answer to your F3

Comment: Did, but no luck. Would you please upload your file to cloud and send me the link?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VOQpsTxe6tdamuc_T8ahrXW--hJP92R1/view

Comment: Got the point which is Curley braces {.....} at the beginning and ending of formula in F1 and F2. May I know when to use those curly braces?

Comment: It means its an array formula, see more here https://www.lifewire.com/excel-multi-cell-array-formulas-3123733

Comment: Thank You for all of your help.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Regarding the reply of @SQL Temp #SQL Temp.

Comment: Can you format column A & E as 'Text'

Comment: Done but did not work. Is there any way to send me your file, perhaps in a private message?

Comment: Upload to dropbox, make public and send me the link

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/uu2uhut4u0srbkad7xq6s/Book1.xlsx?dl=0&rlkey=fvqsu8t8e2m9dvjawzl5xrunw

Comment: See updated answer,